# Using SonicWALL SSL VPN with mobile devices

Tags: vpn, ssl, sonicwall, ipad

Can someone point me to some resources talking about using a SonicWALL SSL VPN client with mobile devices (Blackberry, iPhone, iPad, no Android at this time)?

I am not sure how this would work from a user perspective. With iOS say, does SonicWALL provide a app on the Apple Appstore that would perform the authentication with the corporate firewall? Would authenticated users be able to run Windows enterprise applications natively on their mobile devices? Conceptually, would this be the same as using a RDP client "app" over the authenticated SSL VPN tunnel?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a pretty straightforward walkthrough:

Sonicwall: http://www.solved.it/vpn_l2tp_iphone_ipad_ipod_touch_apple_1.php
IOS: http://www.solved.it/vpn_l2tp_iphone_ipad_ipod_touch_apple.php

Comment: @Chris - Thanks for those tutorials, very helpful. Let me see if I understand. So at the end of Part2 Step 8, my iOS device is securely connected to my corporate network. Now what? My corporate intranet is 100% Windows/IE based. How can I launch my corporate Intranet homepage, portal, browser-based apps? Thanks

Comment: Once you're connected to the VPN, you can just fire up Safari, your remote desktop app of choice, etc. and go to work just as you would if you were connecting from a laptop. Granted, if the web apps have any compatibility issues when accessing them with Safari, you'll be in a bit of a bind.

Comment: Yes, one thing I do is remote desktop if I absolutely have to have everythign work.  But it should be transparent to Safari, just like db2 said.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Would a Blackberry have to go through the Blackberry browser/BES or can it use the regular Internet browser?

Comment: I would think the regular browser would work perfectly, but have no experience to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS at least, you'll have to enable L2TP on the Sonicwall and connect via the built-in VPN client. That's the theory, anyway - I've been trying to assist a client with this lately and not having a great deal of success. I'm not a Sonicwall expert, however.